# simple example of electron app with spectron test

Tags: javascript, electron, mocha.js, spectron

I am trying to learn how to test apps, build with electron, using spectron.
for this I took an example application from the web with a simple header, counter label, and incrementer button.

I use mocha as a test runnen.

The test should launch the app, push the button and check the counter label.

I can't even get to the point where the app is launched properly.

I am getting the error " TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitUntilWindowLoaded' of undefined" when I run the test.

Also when looking at the launched app I see an error in the devtools:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')

let win

function createWindow() {
   win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
   win.loadURL(url.format ({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
   }))

   // open dev tools
   win.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>Hello World!</title>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" 
         href = "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class = "container">
         <h1>This page is using Bootstrap and jQuery!</h1>
         <h3 id = "click-counter"></h3>
         <button class = "btn btn-success" id = "countbtn">Click here</button>
         <script src = "./view.js" ></script>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

view.js

```
let $ = require('jquery')  // jQuery now loaded and assigned to $
let count = 0
$('#click-counter').text(count.toString())
$('#countbtn').on('click', () => {
   count ++ 
   $('#click-counter').text(count)
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "gui_testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "app to test spectron",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "ACW",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^7.1.7",
    "mocha": "^6.2.2",
    "spectron": "^9.0.0"
  }
}
```

./test/index.js

```
const assert = require('assert')
const path = require('path')
const { Application } = require('spectron')
const electronPath = require('electron') // Require Electron from the binaries included in node_modules.
const baseDir = path.join(__dirname, '..')

const sleep = time => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, time))

describe('Application launch', function () {
    this.timeout(30000)

    const app = new Application({
        path: electronPath,
        args: [baseDir]
    })

    before(function () { app.start() })

    after(function () { app.stop() })

    it('show an initial window', async function () {
        await app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded();
        const count = await app.client.getWindowCount();
        assert.equal(count, 1)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your browser window like this.

```
win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
})
```

Then this will resolve the undefined require issue.

Comment: then, what is the another issue?

Comment: The 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitUntilWindowLoaded' of undefined'

Answer (score 1):

after googling and trying for a few days I found that disabling "devtools" seems to resolve the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitUntilWindowLoaded' of undefined"

How can this be related?

Answer (score 0):

i added more steps to the test flow and keep running into similar problems.
now my "index.js" contains a test like this:

> ```
> it('click button', async () => {
>     await app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded()
>     await sleep(1000)
>     const btnH = await app.client.$('#countbtn')
>     await btnH.click()
>     await sleep(1000)
>     app.client.$('#countbtn').click()
>     await sleep(1000)
>     const txt = await app.client.$('#click-counter').getText()
>     return assert.equal(txt, '2')
> })
> ```

for some reason i get the error

> TypeError: btnH.click is not a function
>         at Context. (test\index.js:38:20)
>         at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

If I execute the click() directly on the app.client.$('#countbtn') it works.
But if I store the result in a variable first I get the error.

Comment: Share your full test script