# how to communicate between react and electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Creating desktop application using react and electron.I want to call method in main.js of electron from react component.In angular there was a npm package.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './diagnosis.css';
const electron = window.require('electron');// if i use require('electron') throws error
function Diagnosis(props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ hits: [] });
    useEffect(() => {
        getExeFiles();
    });
    const getExeFiles = () => {
        electron.ipcRenderer.send('get-exe'); 
    }
    return(<></>)
}
```

main.js

```
electron.ipcMain.on('get-exe', () => {
    console.log('reaciovg');
    mainWindow.webContents.send('return-exe', '');
});
```

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: At your main process, the *reaciovg* string is being shown correctly?

Comment: its just a console(to check whether the even is triggered).

Comment: socket.io is a good alternative way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At your Renderer.js

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

async function runCommand(cmd) {
  const res = await ipcRenderer.sendSync('runCommand', cmd);
  return res;
}
```

At you main.js

```
// Listen event through runCommand channel
// And return the result to Renderer.
ipcMain.on('runCommand', async (event, arg) => {
  event.returnValue = await runCommand(arg);
});
```

This is the simplest way to communicate between main and renderer process.

But I think you are going to send the result from the main process to renderer using `mainWindow.webContents.send('return-exe', '');`

So this means, you are sending the result through `return-exe` IPC channel from main to renderer. And you should listen event from this channel at your renderer. Like this

```
ipcRenderer.on('retrun-exe', (event, arg) => {
    ...
});
```

You can add this listener at your lifecycle functions. I was used to add this to `componentDidMount()` But in your case, please add this to your `useEffect()`

Comment: UI is not correctly rendering ..It triggers the event

Comment: how to listen to main process to renderer event in react..Why that ui half renders.

Comment: @Krazy to use your require check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533379/simple-example-of-electron-app-with-spectron-test/59534342#59534342

Comment: Simple to use require directly. You should enabled the nodeIntegration flag as true when you creating browserWindow

Comment: @Krazy. What do you mean by *Why that ui half renders*

Comment: I was used to set the listener at **componentDidMount** lifecycyle function like this.

`componentDidMount() {
    ipcRenderer.on('runCommand',(ev, data)=>{
        this.forceUpdate();
    });
}`
```

Comment: So in your case, please add this to your `useEffect()`

Comment: why we can't directly use require instead of window.require.because what I'm doing now is I'm hosting react app in herkou and providing hosted url. Now its throwing error for window.require in browser but not in electron..is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: @Krazy. You should check this. Actually, this is really common but a little bit confusing issue.
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300. You can find the answer as you need here.