# How to call a function is renderer.js/main.js from web page in electron

Tags: electron

Newbie to electron here, I have built a simple web application with React JS and able to view it in a window by calling

```
window.loadFile('./build/index.html');
```

Now i would want to call a function located in say renderer.js/main.js which should read file system and return data to the web application.

I have already tried this in renderer.js

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

document.getElementById('#button').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    //read file contents
    console.log('file contents');
});
```

But there are 2 issues around here

1. The control is from the renderer.js, instead i would want the
   control to be on the web page of React.
2. The data that is read should be returned back to web page, so that it can be displayed in the web page.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to import/require ipcRenderer directly on your react component scripts and maybe load the file on a lifecycle hook. The 'renderer.js' is just one way to execute client side javascript on the (electron-)web page but any other way also does the trick.

If you can't import or require electron from the webapp (I didn't play with the electron-react-boilerplate yet), then you could write a so called preload script, load that when you create the browser window (see that documentation) and put the ipcRenderer on window like so:

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer
```

Then you can access it from the react app.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use `fs` inside the event listener

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const fs = require("fs");

document.getElementById('#button').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  console.log(fs.readFileSync("some/file/path", "utf8"));
});
```

> Electron exposes full access to Node.js both on main and renderer process

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#using-nodejs-apis

Comment: if you enable node integration on the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You are building your electron renderer using React.

Please check this to clear [what main process is and renderer is.](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes)

[how to communicate between react and electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681069/how-to-communicate-between-react-and-electron/59681218#59681218)

This is the answer I posted before. Feel free to check this.

And here is the pre-requirement.

```
let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
  {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences:{
      nodeIntegration:true
    }
  });
```

You should enable the `nodeIntegration` flag when you are creating the BrowserWindow. So that you can use any Nodejs API at your renderer