# Electron.js/Parcel Error: fs.existsSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, parceljs

I am using the Electron/Parcel boilerplate [`electron-react-parcel-boilerplate`](https://github.com/kumarryogeshh/electron-react-parcel-boilerplate) which works great out of the box.

However, when using the [`redux-beacon-electron`](https://github.com/jondot/redux-beacon-electron) package, I am getting the following error in the electron JS console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
    at getElectronPath (index.js:7)
    at Object.parcelRequire.node_modules/electron/index.js.fs (index.js:18)
    at newRequire (src.a2b27638.js:47)
    at localRequire (src.a2b27638.js:53)
    at Object.parcelRequire.node_modules/electron-ga/lib/side-effects.js.electron (side-effects.ts:1)
    at newRequire (src.a2b27638.js:47)
    at localRequire (src.a2b27638.js:53)
    at Object.parcelRequire.node_modules/electron-ga/lib/helpers.js.qs (helpers.ts:4)
    at newRequire (src.a2b27638.js:47)
    at localRequire (src.a2b27638.js:53)
```

and in the terminal where we run `yarn start`:

```
[0] ⚠️  /Users/nyxynyx/electron-app/node_modules/electron/index.js:8:41: Cannot statically evaluate fs argument
[0]    6 | function getElectronPath () {
[0]    7 |   if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {
[0] >  8 |     var executablePath = fs.readFileSync(pathFile, 'utf-8')
[0]      |                                         ^
[0]    9 |     if (process.env.ELECTRON_OVERRIDE_DIST_PATH) {
[0]   10 |       return path.join(process.env.ELECTRON_OVERRIDE_DIST_PATH, executablePath)
[0]   11 |     }
```

[image]

My gut feeling is that Parcel was not properly targeting Electron when starting it using `yarn start`, so I tried changing

```
"react-start": "parcel -p 3000 index.html --out-dir build",
```

to

```
"react-start": "parcel -p 3000 index.html --out-dir build --target node",
```

and

```
"react-start": "parcel -p 3000 index.html --out-dir build --target electron",
```

but now the Electron app does not even launch on running `yarn start`, and nothing appears when trying to load http://localhost:3000 either after running `yarn start` or `yarn react-start`.

Why is it not working and is it possible to solve this error?

Thank you!

---

**GitHub Repo**

https://github.com/nyxynyx/electron-react-parcel-boilerplate-problem

---

Using

- react-dom@16.13.1
- react-redux@7.2.0
- react@16.13.1
- redux-beacon-electron@1.0.1
- redux@4.0.5
- electron@8.2.3
- parcel-bundler@1.12.4

**packages.json**

```
{
  "name": "electron-react-parcel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Electron app build using ReactJS and Parcel web application bundler",
  "main": "src/electron.js",
  "scripts": {
    "react-start": "parcel -p 3000 index.html --out-dir build",
    "react-build": "parcel build index.html --out-dir build --public-url ./",
    "electron-build": "electron-builder -mwl",
    "clean-build": "rm -rf build/ .cache dist/",
    "build": "yarn clean-build && yarn react-build && yarn electron-build",
    "start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron . \"",

...
```

---

### `nodeIntegration: true`

Tried setting to `true` as suggested by @tpikachu, but the same error persists...

**electron.js** (usually named `main.js`)

```
function createWindow() {
  const { width, height } = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: Math.round(width * 0.9),
    height: Math.round(height * 0.9),
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    }
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
  );
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => (mainWindow = null));
}


app.on("ready", async () => {
  createWindow();

  ...

});
```

Comment: Where are you using this node module, redux-beacon-electron? Renderer or Main

Comment: @tpikachu In the renderer, where there is a React/Redux app.

Comment: Then please enable the `nodeIntegration` flag when you are creating `BrowserWindow`

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60400263/how-to-call-a-function-is-renderer-js-main-js-from-web-page-in-electron/60404701#60404701

Comment: @tpikachu Enabled `nodeIntegration` as suggested, but the error is still appearing.

Comment: Can I check your repo if this is open-source?

Comment: @tpikachu Good idea, I have just created a repo to reproduce the problem: https://github.com/nyxynyx/electron-react-parcel-boilerplate-problem

Comment: I couldn't installed the dependencies correctly due to this

Comment: `warning "redux-beacon-electron > electron-ga@1.0.6" has incorrect peer dependency "electron@^1.8.2".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[6/8] ⠈ deasync
[-/8] ⠈ waiting...
[7/8] ⠈ electron
[-/8] ⠈ waiting...
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/legendarypanda/Documents/electron-react-parcel-boilerplate-problem-master/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild`

Comment: electron-ga@1.0.6 has electron@^1.8.2 has peer dependency

Comment: @tpikachu Thanks for identifying the cause! Electron 1.8.2 very old. My app is currently using elctron 8.2.3. Do you think there is a quick fix without downgrading the electron used in my electron app to v1.8.2?

Comment: @tpikachu Any suggestions on how to continue using Google Analytics in an Electron app, ideally able to track via Redux actions?

Comment: You can use this `electron-google-analytics` rather than `electron-ga`

Comment: I believe you can configure this with Redux.

Comment: @tpikachu Switching to `electron-google-analytics` works for my purposes. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I will post a full answer. Glad to hear that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to conflicts of package versions. Such as `electron-ga@1.0.6 has electron@^1.8.2`

Even we fix the package conflicts using electron-ga@1.0.6 won't be stable and not fit for the latest electron version.

We can use [`electron-google-analytics`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-google-analytics) rather than `electron-ga`